# Why does networkx.degree_assortativity_coefficient raise a runtime warning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, networkx

I am running into an issue with an `networkx` script I wrote. I think this line causes the problem:

```
nx.degree_assortativity_coefficient(G)
```

---

```
lib/python3.7/site-packages/networkx/algorithms/assortativity/correlation.py:288: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  return (xy * (M - ab)).sum() / numpy.sqrt(vara * varb)
```

If I go to the `networkx` [source code](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.2/_modules/networkx/algorithms/assortativity/correlation.html) this function causes the warning:

```
def numeric_ac(M):
    # M is a numpy matrix or array
    # numeric assortativity coefficient, pearsonr
    try:
        import numpy
    except ImportError:
        raise ImportError('numeric_assortativity requires ',
                          'NumPy: http://scipy.org/')
    if M.sum() != 1.0:
        M = M / float(M.sum())
    nx, ny = M.shape  # nx=ny
    x = numpy.arange(nx)
    y = numpy.arange(ny)
    a = M.sum(axis=0)
    b = M.sum(axis=1)
    vara = (a * x**2).sum() - ((a * x).sum())**2
    varb = (b * x**2).sum() - ((b * x).sum())**2
    xy = numpy.outer(x, y)
    ab = numpy.outer(a, b)
    return (xy * (M - ab)).sum() / numpy.sqrt(vara * varb)
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Looks to me like if any of the columns or rows in M is zero, the denominator in the returned expression becomes zero, resulting in inf or NaN values.

Answer (score 0):

This is relevant with your graph.

For example, a complete graph will always lead to a such problem, because `vara` and `varb` in a complete graph are all 0. Dividing 0 causes the "invalid value encountered in double_scalars" warning.

Apart from this extreme situation, we can't calculate the assortativity of some other graphs, either. To figure out why, I strongly recommend you to check the formula for assortativity:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assortativity

Notice that undirected graph and directed graph are different. The latter could have 4 pair of assortativity. (i.e. (in,in), (out,out), (in,out), (out,in))